# Transform each group in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following DataFrame:

```
  id   x    y        timestamp  sensorTime
   1   32   30        1031      2002
   1   4    105       1035      2005
   1   8    110       1050      2006
   2   18   10        1500      3600
   2   40   20        1550      3610
   2   80   10        1450      3620
....


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,1,2,2,2], [32,4,8,18,40,80], [30,105,110,10,20,10], [1031,1035,1050,1500,1550,1450], [2002, 2005, 2006, 3600, 3610, 3620]])).T
df.columns = ['id', 'x', 'y', 'timestamp', 'sensorTime]
```

For each group grouped by `id` I would like to add the differences of the `sensorTime` to the first value of `timestamp`. Something like the following:

```
start = df.iloc[0]['timestamp']
df['sensorTime'] -= df.iloc[0]['sensorTime']
df['sensorTime'] += start
```

But I would like to do this for each `id` group separately.

The resulting DataFrame should be:

```
  id   x    y        timestamp  sensorTime
   1   32   30        1031      1031
   1   4    105       1035      1034
   1   8    110       1050      1035
   2   18   10        1500      1500
   2   40   20        1550      1510
   2   80   10        1450      1520
....
```

How can this operation done per group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df

    id  x   y timestamp sensorTime
0   1   32  30  1031    2002
1   1   4   105 1035    2005
2   1   8   110 1050    2006
3   2   18  10  1500    3600
4   2   40  20  1550    3610
5   2   80  10  1450    3620
```

You can group by `id` and then pass both `timestamp` and `sensorTime`. Then you can use [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) to get the difference of `sensorTime`. The first value would be `NaN` and you can replace it with the first value of `timestamp` of that group. Then you can simply do [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to get the desired output.

```
def func(x):
    diff = x['sensorTime'].diff()
    diff.iloc[0] = x['timestamp'].iloc[0]
    return (diff.cumsum().to_frame())

df['sensorTime'] = df.groupby('id')[['timestamp', 'sensorTime']].apply(func)
df
    id  x   y timestamp sensorTime
0   1   32  30  1031    1031.0
1   1   4   105 1035    1034.0
2   1   8   110 1050    1035.0
3   2   18  10  1500    1500.0
4   2   40  20  1550    1510.0
5   2   80  10  1450    1520.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could run a groupby twice, first, to get the difference in sensorTime, the second time to do the cumulative sum:

```
box = df.groupby("id").sensorTime.transform("diff")
df.assign(
    new_sensorTime=np.where(box.isna(), df.timestamp, box),
    new=lambda x: x.groupby("id")["new_sensorTime"].cumsum(),
).drop(columns="new_sensorTime")


    id  x   y   timestamp   sensorTime  new
0   1   32  30      1031    2002    1031.0
1   1   4   105     1035    2005    1034.0
2   1   8   110     1050    2006    1035.0
3   2   18  10      1500    3600    1500.0
4   2   40  20      1550    3610    1510.0
5   2   80  10     1450     3620    1520.0
```